# Jest test: Cannot find module '../Link.react' from 'Link.react.js'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to setup jest test following https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react I have installed the jest related dependencies, created `__test__/link.react.test.js` and `Link.react.js`. Following is my structure:
[image]

However, it has problem for the test as following. But My structure and two files are exactly same as the tutorial.

```
FAIL  __tests__/link.react.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '../Link.react' from 'Link.react.js'

       5 | 
       6 | import React from 'react';
    >  7 | import Link from '../Link.react';
         | ^
       8 | import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
       9 | 
      10 | it('renders correctly', () => {
```

Comment: could you try change file name from `Link.react.js` to `Link.js`. And change in the `link.react.test.js` file the path to `Link`

Comment: works! Could you plz post as answer I will accept it. But it is so strange, the tutorial use the same filename and the tutorial works! I was wondering if you know the reason

Comment: It was just my intuitive suggestion. I think system can not recognize that the file extension is `js` because of `.react` in file name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change file name from `Link.react.js` to `Link.js`. And change in the `link.react.test.js` file the path to `Link`. Sorry, I don't know exactly why it will work :)